# Best Way to Ask for my Referral Bonus

Tags: bonus, referral

I'm working for a company that has an Employee Referral Bonus. Four months ago I referred a colleague and he was hired on.

I'm looking for the best way to ask for the referral bonus stated in the employee handbook.

Policy:

> **Employee Referral Bonus**
>  A referral/recruitment bonus may be paid to full-time employees who refer an individual to Employer that
>   is hired to meet the requirements of an open position. The referred
>   employee must be a full-time employee for three consecutive months
>   before the referral bonus is paid to the referring employee. The
>   referral bonus and its amount are set by senior management.

Any help is welcomed, I'm trying to work on my tact.

Comment: A friend had a similar situation, result was the management came back and said one of their colleagues had "found" the person prior to the recommendation of my friend... But good luck you may be ok...

Comment: `I'm looking for the best way to ask for the referral bonus stated in the employee handbook.` - Ummm... ask for it? Why is this difficult?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't stress too much. Send an email to the HR department. This is bread and butter for them. Ask them what the process is to claim it.

Comment: ...just be ready for potential rejection, many of these policies strictly require the employee to mention you as the referrer on the job app, if they didn't do that, you may be out of luck. Strict rules like this are enforced to prevent people from colluding after the fact ("Hey, you're a new hire? Go tell HR I referred you and I'll give you half the bonus!")

Comment: @dwizum That's very interesting to me, and probably depends on culture etc. Usually, at least where I'm from, the referral is like you vouching for someone, and putting your reputation on the line to assist the business finding talent. If you, after the fact, go to the business, then they haven't used your advise during the hiring process.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a sample email I have written to ask referral bonus to my HR**

Subject: Employee Referral Bonus

Dear HR Name,

I have referred one of my colleagues ***referred person name*** to ***your company name***. He/she got selected and joined us on DD/MM/YYYY.

As per ***your company name*** Employee Referral policy, let me know the process to claim the referral bonus. Below are the details of the employee for your reference. Let me know if you need any additional information.

**Name**: XXX

**Email ID**: XXX@yy.com

**Date of Joining**: DD/MM/YYYY

**Employee ID**: XXXXX

Thanks,

Your Name